# How can i convert two different Jsons with some common entities into a pojo?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, pojo

I have two almost same (but not exactly) json types. How can i convert them both in common POJO ? I also want to validate to check weather a given json matches with structure any of my two structure.

*Pojo requires following :*

1. Data > id
2. User
3. link
4. Images / Videos all resolution links
5. Type (image or video)

Json1 : Image

```
    {
    "data": {
        "id": "1463702032229439702_1213175392",
        "user": {
            "id": "1213175392",
            "full_name": "Shubh Patel",
            "profile_picture": "8479268741375_3699247309045891072_a.jpg",
            "username": "imshubhpatel"
        },
        "images": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150,
                "url": "16906688_1657380991225027_6267811870028070912_n.jpg"
            },
            "low_resolution": {
                "width": 320,
                "height": 320,
                "url": "7380991225027_6267811870028070912_n.jpg"
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640,
                "url": "991225027_6267811870028070912_n.jpg"
            }
        },
        "created_time": "1488706901",
        "caption": {
            "id": "17862995743119798",
            "text": "#free #sunday #friends\n\ud83d\udcf7#galaxyS7edge #filter",
            "created_time": "1488706901",
            "from": {
                "id": "1213175392",
                "full_name": "Shubh Patel",
                "profile_picture": "375_3699247309045891072_a.jpg",
                "username": "imshubhpatel"
            }
        },
        "user_has_liked": true,
        "likes": {
            "count": 69
        },
        "tags": [
            "galaxys7edge",
            "filter",
            "friends",
            "sunday",
            "free"
        ],
        "filter": "Lo-fi",
        "comments": {
            "count": 1
        },
        "type": "image",
        "link": "m/p/BRQHT5IDZjW/",
        "location": {
            "latitude": 23.0269676032,
            "longitude": 72.6177998974,
            "name": "Amadavad, Gujarat, India",
            "id": 323843626
        },
        "attribution": null,
        "users_in_photo": [

        ]
    },
    "meta": {
        "code":  200
    }
}
```

Json 2 : Video

```
    {"data":{
      "id":"1446990997590161365_3528222307",
      "user":{
         "id":"3528222307",
         "full_name":"Quotes",
         "profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13636186_1007201962683005_401121573_a.jpg",
         "username":"paper_quote"
      },
      "images":{
         "thumbnail":{
            "width":150,
            "height":150,
            "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/16464045_378045945896668_5822871099456618496_n.jpg"
         },
         "low_resolution":{
            "width":320,
            "height":320,
            "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/16464045_378045945896668_5822871099456618496_n.jpg"
         },
         "standard_resolution":{
            "width":612,
            "height":612,
            "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/16464045_378045945896668_5822871099456618496_n.jpg"
         }
      },
      "created_time":"1486714790",
      "caption":{
         "id":"17861817805113444",
         "text":"#writer #when #a #man #loves #you",
         "created_time":"1486714790",
         "from":{
            "id":"3528222307",
            "full_name":"Quotes",
            "profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13636186_1007201962683005_401121573_a.jpg",
            "username":"paper_quote"
         }
      },
      "user_has_liked":false,
      "likes":{
         "count":8
      },
      "tags":[
         "loves",
         "a",
         "when",
         "you",
         "writer",
         "man"
      ],
      "filter":"Clarendon",
      "comments":{
         "count":0
      },
      "type":"video",
      "link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BQUvqVUjLfV/",
      "location":null,
      "attribution":null,
      "users_in_photo":[

      ],
      "videos":{
         "standard_resolution":{
            "width":480,
            "height":480,
            "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/16551387_391810901170749_7519844898950873088_n.mp4"
         },
         "low_bandwidth":{
            "width":480,
            "height":480,
            "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/16551387_391810901170749_7519844898950873088_n.mp4"
         },
         "low_resolution":{
            "width":480,
            "height":480,
            "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/16551387_391810901170749_7519844898950873088_n.mp4"
         }
      }},"meta":{
      "code":200}}
```

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I converted this json to  POJO and then used gson like this **Media media = new Gson().fromJson(response, Media.class);** but even my response in different json schema, it's not giving me any error.

Comment: You could also post the mapping class (POJO) so there could be not secrets in your question like is the `Media` class `abstract` or not, does it use "polymorphic" fields or it's supposed to be subclassed to add new fields, etc.

Comment: I have not make any POJOs yet. please suggest me